# How to determine layout of ListView not based on position when recycling

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-cursoradapter

I have extended CursorAdapter and associated it with a ListView. I have two different layouts for the rows and have implemented `getViewTypeCount`, `getItemViewType`, `newView` and `bindView`. The data comes from an SQL table where each row has a **layout column** that indicates what kind of layout this item should have.

My `getViewTypeCount` looks like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
int layout = mCursor.getInt(mLayoutIndex);

if (layout == DataHelper.LIST_LAYOUT_ADD_PROJECT)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;   
}
```

But this seems to screw up the recycling of views.

How can this be accomplished? Or is this a bad way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't store the layout integer ID in persistent storage, these IDs can (and will) change with later compilations based on the order and names of things, so it will most likely come bite you later. This might actually be the source of your troubles.

The other thing that I see is that you don't use the `position` argument that was provided to you, so how do you know that the data in `mCursor` corresponds to the current position being queried?

Comment: The layout ID is not the resource ID that is provided when R is built, so it's not changing between compilations. I found out that position is not needed when working with a cursors since it seems to be set correctly by the framework, so I just keep a reference to the cursor and it will always be the current item/row.

Comment: When the CursorAdapter recycles views the framework uses the getItemViewType to determine what view type it should pick from the pool of recycled views (at least this is how I understand it). And this is where my implementation doesn't work -it seems that you *have* to use the "position" in the list to determine its type. But I would like to use the data I have stored in my DB.

Comment: In other words, when views goes outside of the screen and you scroll back and it comes back into the screen getItemViewType gets called but my cursors is not associated with that view. So I get random layouts for views that are being recycled.

Comment: Seems to me you need to use that `position` argument.

Comment: Yeah, it seems. My question would then be how to implement this in another way. I mean there must be some kind of way to determine the type of layout you want and **not** relying on the position in the list.